# Slickgrid issue with Composite Editor for LongText column

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Can anyone help me in fixing the below issue where am using the compositeEditor for editing, But getting the below issue the longtext field is overlapping the columns as shown below. Please help me in resolving this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to fix in the slick library js files. But, I just found the simple solution. You can just bind below script into event of a button which will call compositeEditor. You will have to find CSS path of the div that you want to push down.

```
$('body > div.item-details-form > div:nth-child(4)').css("margin-bottom","100px");
```